# Handling Shift+Del

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am having a `DataGridView` in a `winform` with delete handled which authenticates and deletes those rows. However, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> deletes the rows from `UI`. I have tried setting a `boolean` *`IsShiftPressed`* by handling *`keydown`* event but that looks ugly. Surely there should be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try in `KeyUp Event`

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Del && e.Shift)
{
   if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
   {
      //Do Stuff
   }
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to [trap the control in C# according to this article.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320584).

```
class MyDataGrid : System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid
{
   protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
   {
            const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
            const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

            if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
            {
                switch (keyData)
                {
                    case Keys.Shift | Keys.Delete:
                        MessageBox.Show("shift + del pressed");
                        break;
                }
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
   }
}
```